# Error compiling Jenkins plugin using Java and Maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I'm hoping somebody could help. I'm trying to compile a simple plugin for Jenkins/Hudson that will execute code on a slave, however this block of code is failing to compile:

```
// Define what should be run on the slave for this build
Callable<String, IOException> task = new Callable<String, IOException>() {
    public String call() throws IOException {
        // This code will run on the build slave
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    }
};
// Get a "channel" to the build machine and run the task there
String hostname = launcher.getChannel().call(task);
```

I'm getting an exception when trying to compile when declaring the Callable variable Task. The error is 'error: wrong number of type arguments; required 1'.

I'm new to both creating jenkins plugins and Java so I'm hoping someone more experienced could aid me. I've googled extensively and the documentation suggests I'm doing the right thing (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.hudson.main/remoting/1.366/hudson/remoting/Callable.java#Callable) which is why I've came up stuck.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you somehow compiling against 'java.util.concurrent.Callable' rather than 'hudson.remoting.Callable'?

Comment: Hi Nick, this was exactly my problem. I've switched to now importing the latter and it all builds correctly. If you can add this as an answer then I can mark it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Added as an answer, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you compiling against 'java.util.concurrent.Callable' rather than 'hudson.remoting.Callable'? Check the import statements.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at a really old version of the Jenkins code.  Here are links to the [current JavaDo](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/overview-summary.html)c and the [latest cod](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins)e.

It looks as if the Remoting class that you were trying to use doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Hi Gareth, whilst this wasn't the issue (see Nick's comment above), it's definitely handy to have these links and take a look, so thank you.